# PHP count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Tags: php, count

Here is a snippet of my code in the file
*public_html/wp-content/themes/arabv3/CustomMetaBox/CMB2.php*, starting at  line 565

```
        // if it's an array of one, extract it
    elseif ( is_array( $this->prop( 'object_types' ) ) && count( $this->prop( 'object_types' ) === 1 ) ) {
        $cpts = $this->prop( 'object_types' );
        $type = is_string( end( $cpts ) )
            ? end( $cpts )
            : false;
    }
```

When I run the code I get the following error:

> PHP Warning:  count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in

Comment: obviously the property which `count()` acts on is not an array or countable, referring to `$this->prop('object_types')`. It acts on a boolean since the `count()` features a comparison within

Comment: You have a typo. Change `count($this->prop('object_types') === 1 )` to `count($this->prop('object_types')) === 1`.

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP version ? if its 7.2 then count function give you error when you count stdclass .

**Example:**

```
$count_value = stdClass Object( [asset_id] => 234 [parent_asset_id] => '');

echo count($count_value);
```

//this give an error in case of php 7.2 version

you can typecast to an array or make that stdclass as an array .

you can check php doc :-

https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration72.incompatible.php#migration72.incompatible.warn-on-non-countable-types